# Pushing Mercurial changesets from my local clone to "the real" clone?

Tags: mercurial, google-code

I created a project at Google code, and am using Mercurial for it.

I made a clone of the project: `farm-myclone` up on Google code.

I pull out a copy of `farm-myclone`, and start adding files, modifying files, etc.

I use `hg commit`, then `hg push` to get changes back into my clone's repository.

Now I want to move these changes into the real repository, just named `farm`.

Do I just do something like:

```
hg push [farm-myclone] to [farm]
```

so that whatever the state of my clone is gets pushed to the real clone?

Is that right? I'm an SVN user so this is a bit confusing to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got one more clone than you actually need: You probably don't need "farm-myclone" to exist at all on Google Code.

If that main project is just called "farm", then when you run `hg clone` to make a clone of it, you get a clone *on your local machine*. This clone is a full Mercurial repository in all respects. When you're ready to publish your changes for the rest of the world to see, use `hg push` to push them up to the "farm" repository.

I think the presence of the additional "farm-myclone" repository is confusing the issue.

Comment: Ah ok true you are right, I'm not the owner of the project, so the owner had me previously create a clone named "farm-myclone". Now I have been granted full commit access, and was wondering if the above situation makes sense, if I still want the buffer of committing to my own clone copy first? Thanks!

Comment: @user246114: If you think you may be in a position where you want to publish your own changes to the world that are *separate* from the previous project, then you may want to create your own clone. Otherwise, don't worry about it until you know you need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax like the one you suggest -- may I ask where you got it from? I would love to improve the documentation, so please let us know (preferably on the [Mercurial mailinglist](http://www.selenic.com/mailman/listinfo/mercurial/)) how we can improve the output of `hg help push`.

As for your question, then I agree with Greg -- you seem to have an unneeded clone. Often, you'll only have a single other clone to push/pull from. When you do

```
hg clone http://example.org/foo foo-clone
```

then `foo-clone` will have `http://example.org/foo` as its default push/pull path. This means that a simple

```
hg pull
```

inside of `foo-clone` is enough to pull the latest changes from `http://example.org/foo`.

The default path is stored in `foo-clone/.hg/hgrc` and you are welcome to add other paths and/or change the default. So the `hgrc` file may look like this:

```
[paths]
default = http://example.org/foo
alice = http://other-domain.org/foo
experiement = /home/me/foo-experiment
```

You can then use `hg pull alice` to get her changes or `hg push experiment` to push to your own local experimental clone.

These are just shortcuts, you can always push/pull using an explicit URL:

```
hg pull http://bobs-world.org/foo
```

works as well, if Bob has configured his webserver to serve a clone of the `foo` repository.

I hope this helps a bit :-)